# How do I change my username?

Tags: support, user-accounts

how do I do this? A bit confused at the moment. I do not know also how to change my lovely profile picture. Thanks a lot all community friends and brothers and sisters for helping.

Comment: You can get to your profile page by clicking your name, or here https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/57979/devi

Comment: @Binary Worrier - Not sure that helps with altering it. Instead click on your picture at top right of page and then at top left there's an option to edit your profile.

Comment: thanks still trying ? No luck with the picture yet.

Answer (score 4):

On the top of the page, there is a symbol for the badge(s) you've received. Click on it.

There should be three tabs: "Profile", "Activity" and "Edit Profile and Settings". Click on the last one.

There you should be able to update your displayed name and picture.

The direct link, **for you** should be:

http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/edit/57979

See also that meta post: [How can I change my name on a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-a-stack-exchange-site)

Please note that there are some limitations about name changing. You are not allowed to change it too often.

Comment: And don't pick usernames that go against our be nice policy...